# I have different UIImageView heights in my TableViewCell, how can i set the height of the Cell based on the image height?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

currently when the uiimageview is shown in cellForRowAtIndexPath i calculate the height of the image and store it in a CGFloat scaledHeight

how can i resize the cell and make it equal to this height?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object {


    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"PhotoCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


    PFFile *userImageFile = object[@"image"];
    [userImageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (!error) {
//           // UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];


           // imageView.image = image;

            UIImageView *test = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
            test.image = image;

            CGSize imgSize = image.size;
            CGFloat ratio = self.view.window.frame.size.width/imgSize.width;
            CGFloat scaledHeight = imgSize.height * ratio;

            [test setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.window.frame.size.width, scaledHeight)];

            NSLog(@"HEIGHT:%f",scaledHeight);

            [cell addSubview:test];

        }
    } progressBlock:^(int percentDone)

    {
        NSLog(@"done");
    }];
.....
```

here is my heightForRowAtindexPath (i have a general number set 500.0f, but some images are for example 250 in height so theres alot of extra room.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    return 500.0f;

}
```

Comment: I'm afraid you must get the image firstly and then reload the cell.(Don't load image in your cell for index path)

Comment: Add your logic of downloading out of cellForRow.Write download code in separate method.after download completed call reload data..now you have calculated height with you..use it in heightForRow

Comment: @Lumialxk should i download them inside ViewdidLoad?

Comment: @farhan Anywhere you need them. If you don't have the size,reload or insert cell has no effect.

Comment: i just need to get the image set in the cell right when the app is opened if you know what i mean, so i guess viewDidLoad would work.

Comment: Yes,it's the best timing for you.

Comment: Also make sure to reload on main thread.

Comment: would this method still work with PFQueryTableViewController? like everything would be the same as in refreshing, scrolling next page etc.